# EDITED Why can I not compare the dimensions of my objects?

Tags: r, linear-programming

**EDITED QUESTION** I have re-posted this question in simplified form to get to the point more quickly.

I have created the following vector:

```
> scenario1.rhs.reduced2
 [1] 14.400 14.400 14.400 14.400 10.248 19.920 14.400 15.120 14.400 14.400 14.400 14.400 10.416 18.312 12.720 14.400 14.400 14.400 14.400 14.400 14.400 10.248 19.920 14.400 15.120 14.400 14.400 14.400 14.400
[30] 10.416 18.312 12.720 14.400 14.400
```

Just to make sure that it's a vector, I made sure to set the type like this:

```
> scenario1.rhs.reduced2 <- as.vector(scenario1.rhs.reduced2)
```

Yet, when I try to find the length of that vector, this happens:

```
> length(scenario1.rhs.reduced2)
 [1] "1970-01-01 01:00:14 CET" "1970-01-01 01:00:14 CET" "1970-01-01 01:00:14 CET" "1970-01-01 01:00:14 CET" "1970-01-01 01:00:10 CET" "1970-01-01 01:00:19 CET" "1970-01-01 01:00:14 CET" "1970-01-01 01:00:15 CET"
 [9] "1970-01-01 01:00:14 CET" "1970-01-01 01:00:14 CET" "1970-01-01 01:00:14 CET" "1970-01-01 01:00:14 CET" "1970-01-01 01:00:10 CET" "1970-01-01 01:00:18 CET" "1970-01-01 01:00:12 CET" "1970-01-01 01:00:14 CET"
[17] "1970-01-01 01:00:14 CET" "1970-01-01 01:00:14 CET" "1970-01-01 01:00:14 CET" "1970-01-01 01:00:14 CET" "1970-01-01 01:00:14 CET" "1970-01-01 01:00:10 CET" "1970-01-01 01:00:19 CET" "1970-01-01 01:00:14 CET"
[25] "1970-01-01 01:00:15 CET" "1970-01-01 01:00:14 CET" "1970-01-01 01:00:14 CET" "1970-01-01 01:00:14 CET" "1970-01-01 01:00:14 CET" "1970-01-01 01:00:10 CET" "1970-01-01 01:00:18 CET" "1970-01-01 01:00:12 CET"
[33] "1970-01-01 01:00:14 CET" "1970-01-01 01:00:14 CET"
>
```

I have had the exact same nonsensical behaviour with other objects in my simulation, I am guessing it's the same problem. Any ideas about what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Please share some more information about `scenario1.rhs.reduced2`, preferably by using `dput()` so we can inspect it ourselves.

Comment: Okay, I will do that, thanks.

Comment: You need to provide the code you used to initialise the vector. From the input you gave it is not possible to replicate your error.

Comment: Okay, I am going to re-post this as a simplified, newer question. Thanks.